# Is there a tool that can indent mixed code?

Tags: php, javascript, html, netbeans, indentation

I searched around the webs and found tools that can indent java,C,php,HTML etc.
Is there a tool, that can reliably indent mixed sourcecode and different languages?
-> one indent tool to rule them all?
I am looking for a standalone opensource program or even a NetBeans plugin (but there seems to be only jindent).

Comment: Not an *answer* since you specifically said "open source," which this isn't: But WebStorm and IDEA (both from Jetbrains) can reformat mixed source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using NetBeans' own indention functionality ( [SHIFT]+[ctrl]+F - on MacOS ).
It works quite well, though I have to indent by hand sometimes.
For really bad structured code I use the common tools.

Answer (score 0):

The indentation rules for different languages are different. If there were a "universal indenter", it would first determine in which language the text was written, and then invoke what is essentially a language-specific indentation subroutine.

There are packages for LaTeX and the like which can indent more than one language, but you tell them *which* language they're dealing with...

Do you have a particular task you wish to accomplish?

Comment: Sometimes I get code (PHP+HTML+CSS+JS) all in one single file, which is a mess. I had the hope to simplify cleaning it up.

Answer (score -1):

[SourceFormat claims to be a multi-language pretty printer.](http://www.sourceformat.com/pretty-printer.htm) But  it isn't free and only runs on windows.

WebStorm and IDEA (both from Jetbrains) can reformat mixed source, but they aren't open source. (via [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder))

Comment: multi-language != mixed language

Comment: It was just offline for a tick. It's back online now.

Comment: SourceFormat looks interesting, but it isn't free and only runs in windows. What a pitty.